# regex match if word_B and word_C are within N words of each other, and word_A not in the M preceding words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Looking to match 2 words near each other, only if another given word is not preceding (meaning with possible other words in between). We can assume that if word A appears, it will be before word B, and that word B will always be preceding word C.

For example, with N=3, M=2 :

**word_A** word **word_B** word **word_C** || should not match

**word_A** word word **word_B** word || should not match

**word_A** word word word word **word_B** word word **word_C** || should match

word **word_B** word **word_C** || should match

So far, I came up with that : but does not work

```
import regex

matches = regex.findall(r"\b(?<!word_A\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(?:word_B\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?(word_C)", text, regex.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: I suggest that you don't want to do this with regular expressions.  Break up your strings into lists and then deal with the word positions in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of lookaheads, a positive lookahead for `word_B` followed by `word_C` within N words, and a negative lookahead for `word_A` followed by `word_B` within M words:

```
^(?=.*\bword_B\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}\b(word_C)\b)(?!.*\bword_A\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,1}\bword_B\b)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w4XdMg/2/)

In python

```
import re
strings = ['word_A word word_B word word_C',
           'word_A word word word_B word',
           'word_A word word word word word_B word word word_C',
           'word word_B word word_C']
pattern = r'^(?=.*\bword_B\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}\b(word_C)\b)(?!.*\bword_A\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,1}\bword_B\b)'
for str in strings:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, str, re.IGNORECASE)
    print(matches)
```

Output

```
[]
[]
['word_C']
['word_C']
```